# How to override function in Kotlin object?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, migration, overriding

I have some problems with mirgating my application from Java to Kotlin.
I have this class in java, which works great:

```
public final class BooleanUtils extends org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils {

    private BooleanUtils() {
    }

    /**
     * Converts a String to Boolean.
     * @param str  the String to check
     * @return true/false
     */
    public static boolean toBoolean(final String str) {
        return org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils.toBoolean(str) || "1".equals(str);
    }

}
```

and after auto-transform in IntelijiIdea, it began to look like this

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils

object BooleanUtils : BooleanUtils() {
    
    /**
     * Converts a String to Boolean.
     * @param str  the String to check
     * @return true/false
     */
    fun toBoolean(str: String): Boolean {
        return BooleanUtils.toBoolean(str) || "1" == str
    }
}
```

But compiler tells me, that

> Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM
> signature (toBoolean(Ljava/lang/String;)Z):
> fun toBoolean(p0: String?): Boolean defined in my.util.BooleanUtils
> fun toBoolean(str: String?): Boolean defined in my.util.BooleanUtils

How could I override fun toBoolean(str: String), to make it work like in Java?

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer an extension to the String class:

```
fun String.boolean(): Boolean = 
    return when(this.toLowerCase()) {
        "y", "yes", "t", "true", "1" -> true
        else -> false
    }
```

Comment: This will collide with the stdlib-function of almost identical signature. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-boolean.html

Comment: Rename it to asBoolean, then.  Or use the standard lib function.

Comment: The stdlib does not recognize anything but `'true'`. In fact, it delegates to Boolean.parseBoolean.

Comment: I'd use a function like the one I posted if the requirement is to go beyond true.

Comment: I would too. After your adaption to `String.boolean` it looks a lot more viable. I'd call it `truthy` as in the javascript truthyness. But that would extend the semantics a lot.

Comment: I disagree about the "truthy" bit from JavaScript.  It wouldn't suffer from the same null shenanigans and lack of type safety that JavaScript does.